# FFMPEG, how to create custom waveform

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, waveform

I have done research trying to create a waveform with FFMPEG and am currently able to create a white png with the wave being transparent. The goal is to generate the wave like the smooth wave below and have the grey be transparent.
[image: ffmpeg wavform]

Here is my current FFMPEG waveform generator and output.

```
ffmpeg -i ./_test.mp3 -filter_complex \
"[0:a]aformat=channel_layouts=mono,compand=gain=-6, \
showwavespic=s=450x46:colors=white,negate[a]; \
color=white:450x46[c]; \
[c][a]alphamerge"  -vframes 1 _test.png
```

[image: ffmpeg wavform]

Comment: Can't see reference image.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Mulvya. Must have been a drop box share issue. You should be able to see images now.

Comment: I suggest you roll up your sleeves and write some custom code yourself ... audio is just a curve so its surprisingly easy go generate ... SO is for pointed questions with answerable solutions ... your question shows an actual waveform at bottom which once stretched out using a visualization tool like Audacity will eventually appear similar to our topmost image ... no amount of fudging will read in one and generate the other ... when you write our own code to synthesize audio you will appreciate this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to do this in FFmpeg, one because the waveform isn't drawn with a line, but filled polygons, and two because FFmpeg seems to have trouble dealing with millisecond duration audio.

It would probably be possible to do this using more advanced math/plotting software like R, Octave or matplotlib, but my first thought was to use three smaller more specialized command line utilities:

- [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net) to trim, resample and save an audio file to a parseable .dat format
- (grep/sed to clean up the .dat file)
- [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info) to draw a plot based on that .dat file and save as .png
- [Imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to modify the .png so that the plotted line is transparent

In the end my example script ended up like this

```
# create example file
sox -n -r 32k -b 16 pnoise.wav synth 10 pinknoise norm -0.1

# trim/convert
sox --norm=-1 pnoise.wav test.dat remix 1 trim 5 0.002 rate 200k

grep -v "^;" test.dat |\
  sed -e "s/^[[:space:]]*//" -e "s/[[:space:]]*$//" > test.txt

# draw plot    
gnuplot

set term png size 600,200 background "#BBBBBB"

set output "test.png"

unset key
unset border
unset xtics
unset ytics

set margins 0, 0, 0, 0

set yrange [-1:1]

plot "test.txt" with lines lt rgb "#FF0000" lw 3

exit

# replace red opaque with fully transparent
mogrify -channel rgba -matte -fill "#FF000000" -opaque "#FF0000" test.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have looked into wavesurfer I am going to fork it and build a custom solution.